# Upload tasks from NSData are not supported in background sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am trying to upload image using **Share extension** but the problem is when i add the background task it is giving me this error, It is saying nsdata is not supported in background task but wwdc session is uploading the image in nsdata. Will you please let me know where is the problem. and how i can fix it

**Upload tasks from NSData are not supported in background sessions**

```
NSString *boundary = @"SportuondoFormBoundary";

NSString * configurationName = @"com.xxxxxxxx.PhotoSharing.backgroundConfiguration";

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration= [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:configurationName];
[configuration setSharedContainerIdentifier:kGroupNameToShareData];


configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                        @"api-key"       : @"55e76dc4bbae25b066cb",
                                        @"Accept"        : @"application/json",
                                        @"Content-Type"  : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]
                                        };

NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession  sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


for (NSString *key in parameters)
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
NSLog(@"imageDATE, %@", imageData);
if (imageData)
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", @"file"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




// Data uploading task. We could use NSURLSessionUploadTask instead of NSURLSessionDataTask if we needed to support uploads in the background
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kURLBase,kURLAddPostDL]];
NSLog(@"url %@",url);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10000];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = body;



NSURLSessionUploadTask *upload=[session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:request.HTTPBody];
[upload resume];
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems Up `NSURLSessionUploadTask` does not support Large size NSData,
But you can give a file path to `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to upload on server, or write your image temporary on disk firs then give path.

Here's an example it is uploading both the filepath and NSdata.

[Uploads using backgroundSessionConfiguration and NSURLSessionUploadTask cause app to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767334/uploads-using-backgroundsessionconfiguration-and-nsurlsessionuploadtask-cause-ap)

Updated :

```
//Create a file to upload
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"onboarding-4@2x.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *URLs = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[URLs objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString];
```

// Here's the **filePath** URL

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"testfile.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://file.upload/destination"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
```

// Here it is using it **filePath**.

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //code
}];
```

Comment: how can i give url, i check the link but it is not using url

Comment: did you run this code for share extension, this is not working

Comment: for using NSURL with local files, use `[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath]`