# NSURLSession background upload using the chunk transfer

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am using the `NSURLSession` to perform the upload of a file using the chunk transfer.

```
self.dataTask = [self uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromData:urlRequest.HTTPBody progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    //Error response
                } else {
                    //Success response
                }
            }];

            [self.dataTask resume];
```

The issue is that when the app goes to the `background` it will not perform the continuous upload, the ongoing upload will suspend and resumes when app goes to `foreground`.

I want to achieve the background transfer continuously for the chunk upload.

Any suggestion to achieve this?

**Update:**

Implemented the `backgroundSessionConfiguration` and getting the below error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Upload tasks from NSData are not supported in background
>   sessions.

Comment: you should assign background session configuration so that it should work in background.

Comment: Getting the error when I implemented the background session configuration. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Upload tasks from NSData are not supported in background sessions.

Comment: follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660363/upload-tasks-from-nsdata-are-not-supported-in-background-sessions

Comment: You need to write data to local file and grab it from there using filePath to upload on server.