# Making a POST request for a .ts file using NSURLSession in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to make a POST request for .ts files using NSURLSession.  However, what I want to know is, is there a way to do this without converting the .ts files to an NSData object, and without using it inside an NSDictionary?  In other words, can I upload a .ts file directly to the intended URL?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

//I don't want to use the following line 
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1": @"value1"};
NSError *error = nil;

//I don't want to use the following line
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary 
  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (!error) {

 NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
   fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

   }];

   [uploadTask resume];
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the .ts file locally, you could use

```
[session uploadTaskRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL youUrlToTheTSFile]]
```

See the answers here: [Uploads using backgroundSessionConfiguration and NSURLSessionUploadTask cause app to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767334/uploads-using-backgroundsessionconfiguration-and-nsurlsessionuploadtask-cause-ap)

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  One follow up question, what is the difference between using the method, withFile: vs fromFile:?