# Manage the number of active tasks in a background NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

It seems that when you enqueue too many tasks (say, hundreds) on a background `NSURLSession`, it doesn't work well. How can you keep the number of enqueued tasks at a small fixed number, say 10?

Comment: iOS11+ tested: NSURLSession works great for me with hundreds of tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the class that is responsible for enqueueing tasks, have a ivar to track the active tasks, e.g.

```
// In MySessionWrapper.m

@interface MySessionWrapper () {
    NSMutableSet *activeTaskIds;
}
@end
```

When you enqueue a task, you add its ID to that set:

```
[activeTaskIds addObject:@([task taskIdentifier])]
```

When you get a `didComplete` callback, you remove the ID, and if the number of active tasks falls below your
target, you add more tasks:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // other stuff
    [activeTaskIds removeObject:@([task taskIdentifier])]

    if ([activeTaskIds count] < NUMBER) {
        // add more tasks
    }
}
```

This system is working for me now.

Comment: Clay bridges Do i need to add this piece in didComplete __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
 background_task = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ { [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;    }];

Comment: @Xcoder Close. You should _totally_ ask that in a SO question, and I can give you a fuller answer. They format more nicely too. :)

Comment: Clay Bridges.. I will do that. I am in some difficulty now- I have been following several of your posts about NSURLSession managing uploads. Can we have a chat?

Comment: @Clay Do you think long running background tasks interfere with the lifecycle of NSURLSession? I am having a doubt - if a i create a bgtask and dont end it then the application method for handling background session events may never get called.

Comment: @clay heres my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311736/unable-to-sustain-the-upload-of-files-in-the-background-with-nsurlsession

Comment: Hi, is there some github sample of this? I am new and trying to resolve a multi file upload, this is my SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483329/ios-8-multi-file-upload-nsurlsessionuploadtask

Comment: @Huang I personally don't have anything up right. The code I have is both proprietary and deeply intertwined with our product.

Comment: @ClayBridges I understand, question : I assume that all background work is asynchronous, should there by a mutex surrounding the logic in remove and adding active tasks?